# How to fix Error: Stream yields empty buffer in Node.js v14 + GM + ImageMagick

Tags: node.js, docker, imagemagick, image-resizing, gm

How to fix **Error: Stream yields empty buffer** in Node.js v14.15.3?

Here is some code how I use **ImageMagick** to process images:

```
const gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });

const resize = (imageStream, width, height) =>
  new Promise((res, rej) => {
    gm(imageStream.on('error', rej))
      .resize(width, height, '>')
      .noProfile()
      .toBuffer('jpeg', (err, data) => (err ? rej(err) : res(data)));
  });
```

Error throws when image resolution higher than 4000x5000 pixels

```
ImageMagic Resource limits:
  Width: 64MP
  Height: 64MP
  List length: 18.446744EP
  Area: 3.2212GP
  Memory: 2GiB
  Map: 3GiB
  Disk: 10GiB
  File: 786432
  Thread: 2
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: I don't speak `node`, so could you explain 1) how you found those resource limits - I mean what command did you run? 2) I am unclear as regards what size image you start with (in pixels wide by pixels tall) and what size images you end up with. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell
Here is command from official documentation: **identify -list resource**
[link](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#limit)
Input image size can be random(up to 20 000x15 000 pixels)
Resize output should be 1080*1920 and 300*300 px

Comment: Can you be sure that the same resource limits apply within `node` as at the command-line? I have often seen folks use two different installations/versions of **ImageMagick** with different resource limits and mistakenly believing they are using the other version - more so with PHP but nonetheless.